# getting an error in example vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

i am new to vaadin i have compiled 2 codes one is

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloWorld extends com.vaadin.Application {

    /**
     * Init is invoked on application load (when a user accesses the application
     * for the first time).
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {

        // Main window is the primary browser window
        final Window main = new Window("Hello window");
        setMainWindow(main);

        // "Hello world" text is added to window as a Label component
        main.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

it compiles and works fine the other is

```
    import com.vaadin.terminal.ExternalResource;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.Command;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MenuApplication extends VerticalLayout {

    private MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();

    public MenuApplication() {

        // Save reference to individual items so we can add sub-menu items to
        // them
        final MenuBar.MenuItem file = menubar.addItem("File", null);
        final MenuBar.MenuItem newItem = file.addItem("New", null);
        file.addItem("Open file...", menuCommand);
        file.addSeparator();

        newItem.addItem("File", menuCommand);
        newItem.addItem("Folder", menuCommand);
        newItem.addItem("Project...", menuCommand);

        file.addItem("Close", menuCommand);
        file.addItem("Close All", menuCommand);
        file.addSeparator();

        file.addItem("Save", menuCommand);
        file.addItem("Save As...", menuCommand);
        file.addItem("Save All", menuCommand);

        final MenuBar.MenuItem edit = menubar.addItem("Edit", null);
        edit.addItem("Undo", menuCommand);
        edit.addItem("Redo", menuCommand).setEnabled(false);
        edit.addSeparator();

        edit.addItem("Cut", menuCommand);
        edit.addItem("Copy", menuCommand);
        edit.addItem("Paste", menuCommand);
        edit.addSeparator();

        final MenuBar.MenuItem find = edit.addItem("Find/Replace", menuCommand);

        // Actions can be added inline as well, of course
        find.addItem("Google Search", new Command() {
            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                getWindow().open(new ExternalResource("http://www.google.com"));
            }
        });
        find.addSeparator();
        find.addItem("Find/Replace...", menuCommand);
        find.addItem("Find Next", menuCommand);
        find.addItem("Find Previous", menuCommand);

        final MenuBar.MenuItem view = menubar.addItem("View", null);
        view.addItem("Show/Hide Status Bar", menuCommand);
        view.addItem("Customize Toolbar...", menuCommand);
        view.addSeparator();

        view.addItem("Actual Size", menuCommand);
        view.addItem("Zoom In", menuCommand);
        view.addItem("Zoom Out", menuCommand);

        addComponent(menubar);
    }

    private Command menuCommand = new Command() {
        public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
            getWindow().showNotification("Action " + selectedItem.getText());
        }
    };
```

it gets the error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.menu.MenuApplication cannot be cast to com.vaadin.Application
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:966)
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:523)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.menu.MenuApplication cannot be cast to com.vaadin.Application
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:940)
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:768)
 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:431)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

i am using tomcat and eclipse for my development... can any one tell me y i cam getting this error

Comment: `com.example.menu.MenuApplication cannot be cast to com.vaadin.Application` - looks like you're trying to do an illegal typecast.

Answer (score 1):

Your MenuApplication should extend the com.vaadin.Application not the VerticalLayout to be able to use it as Application.

However based on the above sample I'd change the WEB-INF/web.xml to use HelloWorld class instead and change the init() function to include something like:

```
main.addComponent(new MenuApplication());
```

(also consider renaming the MenuApplication, as it is not an Application, but a VerticalLayout)

Comment: This sounds like a good way to go. The classes with extends Application are the one's which should be included in the path in web.xml file. Other files, e.g. your MenuSection/-Layout/ is just like any other Vaadin component which should be added to the Window or some other component container in your Vaadin application.

Comment: Every vaadin application must extend Application class